# get_form_kwargs() from FromSet

Tags: django

```
>>> from django.forms import BaseFormSet
>>> from django.forms import formset_factory
>>> from myapp.forms import ArticleForm

>>> class MyArticleForm(ArticleForm):
...     def __init__(self, *args, user, **kwargs):
...         self.user = user
...         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

>>> ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(MyArticleForm)
>>> formset = ArticleFormSet(form_kwargs={'user': request.user})

The form_kwargs may also depend on the specific form instance. 
The formset base class provides a get_form_kwargs method. 
The method takes a single argument - the index of the form in the formset. 
The index is None for the empty_form:


>>> from django.forms import BaseFormSet
>>> from django.forms import formset_factory

>>> class BaseArticleFormSet(BaseFormSet):
...     def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
...         kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
...         kwargs['custom_kwarg'] = index
...         return kwargs
```

Ive taken the above code from the Django documentation, the documentation says that the form_kwargs which is the dictionary passed in when instantiating FormSet it may depend on a specific instance but it does not say how

When get_form_kwargs() is called in FormSet class with an index, its parent class method get_form_kwargs() is called to retrieve supposedly kwargs from a form instance

Where is kwargs defined for the form instance?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. ```get_form_kwargs``` can be overridden and used for setting specific kwargs for a form instance as shown in the example code you posted.

Comment: What does kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index) do?